# Error compiling Rcpp library with g++: Rcpp.h not found

Tags: c++, r, rcpp

I'm following Hadley's chapter for Rcpp in [Advanced R](http://adv-r.had.co.nz/Rcpp.html), and cannot understand some of the implications of using Rcpp to call C++ functions into R.

In particular, why the C++ files including the directives:

```
#include <Rcpp.h>
using namespace Rcpp;
```

Will lead to a `Rcpp.h not found` error when these files are compiled with g++ as usual, with no R involved.

Is Rcpp.h meant to be called only from R , e.g. using `sourceCpp`? Note that I'd like to maintain the very same C++ file for C++-only programmes, as well as for an R package using Rcpp, but the previous error makes me wonder if this is possible. Am I missing something?

Thank you

**Appendix**

This is the example C++ file from the book. It works great when running `Rcpp::sourceCpp("example.cpp")`, but will lead to the above mentioned compilation error if `g++ -o example example.cpp` is used from a terminal (adding a `main` does not fix that). g++ version is 10.1.0.

```
#include <Rcpp.h>
using namespace Rcpp;

// [[Rcpp::export]]
double meanC(NumericVector x) {
int n = x.size();
double total = 0;
for(int i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
total += x[i];
}
return total / n;
}
/*** R
library(microbenchmark)
x <- runif(1e5)
microbenchmark(
mean(x),
meanC(x)
)
*/
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is an error in your understanding.

> if `g++ -o example example.cpp` is used

No R documentation (that I know of) states you can do that.  If you start where many of us recommend one starts, namely the [Writing R Extensions](https://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/r-release/R-exts.html) manual that also came with your copy of R, you will see that the equivalent commands would be

```
R CMD COMPILE somefile.cpp
R CMD SHLIB somefile.cpp
```

*but* those do *not account for the additional need for Rcpp*.  This actually gets complicated.

But it is a good learning experience to do it all by hand, so some of my older workshops do it, as does [my book on Rcpp](http://www.rcpp.org/book/).

That said, nobody recommends doing it that way for real work. Stick with what is shown in the vignettes [Rcpp Introduction](https://cloud.r-project.org/web/packages/Rcpp/vignettes/Rcpp-introduction.pdf) and maybe [Rcpp Attributes](https://cloud.r-project.org/web/packages/Rcpp/vignettes/Rcpp-attributes.pdf).

Comment: Thank you very much for the explanation and the references Dirk!, it helps clarifying the issue

Comment: No problem. Sometimes it is the little things.  And there is a need for so much documentation (and a reason we have ten vignettes, and the book).  And we sometimes want to be able to compile individual files.  You can arrange your project pretty easily such that, say, `fileGLUE.cpp` deals with the parameter in/out from R and calls an actual work function in `fileWORK.cpp` in which case you can test, profile, compile, ... `fileWORK.cpp` in isolation.  But code interfacing R will ... need R.  Or something like my sibbling project [RInside](http://cloud.r-project.org/package=RInside).